# Mensagem de erro no Login não aparece - LARAVEL 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

Minha aplicação tem um sistema de login feito no laravel com o comando `php artisan`.
Porém quando o usuário erra a senha ou o email, o sistema apenas recarrega a pagina e não retorna a mensagem com erro. O mesmo se aplica quando se via registrar um novo usuário e o email já está cadastrado, a mensagem de erro não é retornada. Não sei onde devo procurar esse erro. 
Esse é meu LoginController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
}
```

Essa é a minha view de Login:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!-- favicon e título -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/storage/imagens/favicon.ico">

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 container-login">
                @if($errors->any())

                <ul class="list-group">

                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)

                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">{{$error}}</li>

                    @endforeach

                </ul>
                @endif

                <form class="col-sm-4 box-login" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <img src="/storage/imagens/logologin.png" alt="Logo" class="img-fluid logo mb-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required placeholder="Senha">
                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" data-loading-text="Aguarde..." class="btn btn-success btn-block mt-4">Entrar</button>
                    <div class="form-group text-right">
                        @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                        <a class="recuperar" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                            {{ __('Esqueceu sua Senha?') }}
                        </a>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Não sei se está errado, já tentei de tudo e nada.

Comment: Melhore a pergunta informando a versão do Laravel e inserindo ao menos o código de uma   das views referentes (arquivo.blade.php)

Answer (score -1):

Verifiquei aqui e está funcionando normalmente como mostra na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema está na minha aplicação, não sei te dizer onde, mas está em algum lugar.Sabe me dizer algum lugar que poderia bloquear essas mensagens?

Comment: @WilliamFreire você tentou atualizar com composer update? Peço que você avalie minha resposta..

Comment: Tentei sim, já fiz o teste em outras aplicações laravel colocando o mesmo código do controller e da view do login e lá funcionou, porém, na minha aplicação não funciona

Comment: minha aplicação vai pra produção essa semana, não da tempo de refazer a aplicação

Comment: Encontrei onde estava o erro. Era no Kernel.php. Meu Kernel possuia essa ultima linha: `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,`. Quando eu tirei essa linha, voltou a exibir as mensagens de erros. Porém estou tenho problemas com minhas API'S. O seguinte erro é exibido: {message: "Não Autorizado", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…} exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"